# Ошибка создания изображений prestashop / nginx + php-fpm

Tags: php, nginx, 1с, php-fpm, ecommerce

Есть: centos 7 / nginx / php-fpm и магазин на prestashop.

Скрипт выгрузки из 1с копирует файлы в каталог site.com/upload/, и оттуда вызывает встроенные функции престы для обработки изображений. 
По какой-то причине файлы не копируются в нужные папки престы, так же не вызывается обработчик - генератор ЧПУ. 
но ссылки на изображения создаются, хотя самих изображений в папках нет : https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpcWt.png ; https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRANu.png

Нигде в логах нет никаких ошибок при выгрузке товара. Вообще ноль. Как это можно отследить, и что это может быть? Грешил на права на файлы / пользователя - но пользователь вроде правильный, нужные права установлены.
Причём на тот же сайт на другом сервере на апаче без проблем всё выгружается/создаётся.

Нужны идеи, предложения где посмотреть, на что обратить внимание. Если нужны конфиги - выложу.